# ownCloud directory renamed / No such file or directory

Tags: owncloud

I installed ownCloud on my webspace (I don't own a server), accessing it with a specific subdomain (i.e. http://sub.domain.com). I now had to rename the originally directory, which I did, and pointed the subdomain to the new directory. Sadly, ownCloud isn't working anymore. So I took a look at the log file:

"Unable to create file (...) No such file or directory"

So I guess ownCloud tries using the old path. Where can I change this setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved the problem - had to change the

```
datadirectory
```

inside the ownCloudPath/config/config.php